# Send mail() from a PHP server different from the one I am working

Tags: php, email

I am in a free web hosting [*hosting A*] but it allows me to send mails via `mail()` (no scripts, nothing: only `mail()`). It works just ok except for the writtens attached at the bottom of each emails and I don't like them at all.

I have a paid hosting [*hosting B*] and I can send emails from it without any written attached.

I would like to keep manage emails from *A* BUT sending from *B* with the less edits I can (headers, bodys and so on). Since *A* is free, doesn't allow to use *PEAR* or anything of the other solutions I've found.

How would you manage this situation?

I was thinking about create a php script in *B* which gets from *A* via *POST* the data and then send them but I don't like from the security point of view (even if I would attach a "key" to be recognized and CURL connections would be in https...

Thank you.

Comment: i see no problem with your purposed solution. I would say hosting is so cheap theses days that i dont see the need for a free host that does this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your current approach (passing email to a script on another server than the one your domain is associated with) is that email authentication checks performed by various email service providers like gmail.com etc. will fail. This may result in your emails getting marked as spam quite often

***Solution 1:***
Create an email account under your paid hosting to be used for sending emails. (You can google the how-to, but the process is straightforward in most hoating control panels)

Setup PhpMailer with your current script hosted on free hosting to send email via smtp using the email account you setup.

***Solution 2:***
Use Mailgun to send emails via its HTTP API or SMTP. Mailgun provides 10k free emails per months. It also provides various useful features like logs, open tracking and click tracking etc.
Checkout https://mailgun.com.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting up a secure API on the second server that needs both a "key" and for the request to come from a white-listed IP.

Here are some tips to make your API secure.

- Always Use HTTPS
- Only stored a hashed version of the key on the remote server.
- Send the key through headers, never in the URL
- Consider using OAuth for authentication
- You can require a timestamp in the header just for a little bit more security. If the timestamp is way off from when the request is made then it is ignored. This can make it slightly more difficult to try to brute-force the key.